# Random start slide in angular bootstrap carousel

Tags: angularjs

Anyone know of a good way to randomize starting slide in the Angular version of Bootstrap Carousel component? I get my slides from a controller:

```
 $scope.slides = [
     {author: "Someone", content: "a content..."},
     {author: "Sometwo", content: "another content"}
     ...
 ];
```

I'm thinking about randomize the ng-repeat output. 
But I actually dont need *everything* randomized, mostly just the starting slide... 
But if this is the best way, then fine!

Is there a way to pass some random start number to the carousel directive?

This doesn't have to be a "real" random function... a Math.random() will do just fine.

Got any good solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!

```
var shuffleArray = function(array) {
        var m = array.length, t, i;

        // While there remain elements to shuffle
        while (m) {
            // Pick a remaining element…
            i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m--);

            // And swap it with the current element.
            t = array[m];
            array[m] = array[i];
            array[i] = t;
        }

        return array;
    }

    shuffleArray($scope.slides);
```